# Using array structs fuction in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, struct

I have an exam. I have league table. There is team name,short name, points etc. as you can see in struct. I have to use function to write a txt file but i can't use function with array structs. My code is below.When i use function like that,codeblocks gives me error. How can i use ?

(**I find my answer. There is a link below,if you need too. 
http://kursattopcuoglu.blogspot.com/2010/06/ilk-donem-final-sorusuna-benzer-bir.html**)

```
struct teams{
char shortname;
char teamname;
int points;
};
void table(struct teams);
int main{
team[2]={'A',"Fenerbahce",0},{'B',"Galatasaray",0};
....
}
void(struct teams team[2]{
printf("%d",team[0].points);
```

Comment: You have not given your function a  NAME... .  `void (struct teams *team)` is missing a name.  Also, you should edit your original question *not add an answer*

Comment: Welcome to [so] please read [ask] and [mcve] to understand why your question is being downvoted.

Comment: To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the error.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the exact errors you get from your [mcve] (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: Replace `team[2]=..` with `struct teams team[2]=...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of answers but none complete. The following is:

```
struct teams{
    char shortname;
    char *teamname;
    int points;
};
void table(struct teams *team);

int main(void){
    struct teams team[2]={{'A',"Fenerbahce",0},{'B',"Galatasaray",0}};
    table(team);
   // ....
}
void table(struct teams *team){
    printf("%d",team[0].points);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the line:

```
/*  .-- function name missing there -- */
    v
void(struct teams* team){
printf("%d",team[0].points);}
```

You are missing a function name.

Answer (score 0):

Even, there are problems with your code.

Considering the `struct teams` that you have defined, the following initializor isn't correct.

```
team[2] = {'A',"Fenerbahce",0},{'B',"Galatasaray",0};
```

For storing a string like `Fenerbahce`, you have to have an array similar to  `char teamname[20]` as an example, rather than just a `char teamname`.

You may use `char *teamname` as well but you have to allocate it some memory as well.

Answer (score -1):

Correct type:

```
    struct teams{
    char shortname;
    char teamname;
    int points;
    };
    void table(struct teams*);
    int main{
    team[2]={'A',"Fenerbahce",0},{'B',"Galatasaray",0};
    ....
    }

void table(struct teams* team){
printf("%d",team[0].points);}
```